# Proposed change to the "Everyday-chemistry" tag wiki (excerpt)

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-wiki

The current [everyday-chemistry](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/everyday-chemistry) wiki excerpt states:

> Applications of chemistry to reagents and reactions of everyday life. This tag should not be applied to questions which are just about simple chemistry but it is specific to questions about chemistry in an out-of-laboratory or commonplace context.

Since questions on everyday oddities involving *physical process* that are studied under chemistry (and not *actual* chemical reactions) seem to do well under this tag, I propose the modification:

> Applications of chemistry to reagents, reactions and processes of everyday life. Use this tag for question on chemistry in an out-of-laboratory/class context. DO NOT use this tag merely because the question is about simple chemistry.

Can I go ahead with this edit?

Comment: I think as a rule you're free to edit as you see fit. They have to be approved anyway, and I suspect even if approved, they'd be modified/rolled back if they were actively harmful. In any case. It seems like a perfectly reasonable edit

Comment: @NotEvans The idea was to pool in ideas (improving the edit itself) from multiple users before I actually try to edit it, so yeah... :P

Comment: I don't like this tag. It's a bit too meta for my taste, it probably gets misapplied every other time, too. No excerpt guidance is going to change this.

Comment: @Mart But still...

Comment: Umm are we supposed to make a meta discussion for every tag edit we do?

Comment: @PrittBalagopal no. It's good to bring such matters to the attention of the community if these are well established tags, but changes that reflect common behaviors don't necessarily need to be discussed in detail every time.

Comment: @Martin I see. I saw paracetamol made two meta posts for tag edits, so I was just wondering.